# Sending Mail with headers and saved in user's Sent Items VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, email, smtpclient

I use this code to send an email using SMTP

```
  Dim clnt As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
            clnt.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            clnt = New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(gate)
            Dim auth_info As System.Net.NetworkCredential = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(toAddress, pass)
            '// MESSAGE SETUP
            Dim msg As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)


            If msg.To.Count = 0 Then Return False

            msg.CC.Clear()
            '// SEND A COPY TO SENDER
            'msg.Bcc.Add(auth_info.UserName)
            msg.Bcc.Add(fromAddress)

            'msg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = Net.Mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure
            'msg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = Net.Mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess
            msg.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", fromAddress)

            msg.Subject = subject

            msg.Body = msgbody
            msg.IsBodyHtml = True
            Dim serverBusy As Boolean = True
            While serverBusy
                Try
                    clnt.Send(msg)
                    serverBusy = False
                Catch
                    serverBusy = True
                End Try

            End While
```

1. With this code the copy of the email is sent to the sender because
   of the bcc property, but in the 'incoming folder'.
2. Because of headers property I achieve to be informed if the receiver
   read the message. A dialog box asks the receiver if he wants the
   sender to be informed that he read the email message, If he
   presses OK then the sender is informed with a new message. The
   problem is that with this implementation the sender is asked with
   the same dialog box when he opens the the copy of the message(bcc
   property).

Comment: I dont think your going to be able to have a msg go directly to a user's `Sent` folder, however you can send a second separate message, but don't add the "notification"  header.

Comment: Ok thank you! As for my second problem? any thoughts?

Comment: #1 is not possible (that I'm aware of).
#2 Send a separate message to the sender without the notification header.